# Минимальное остовное дерево

Tags: графы, дерево, алгоритм, c++

Всем доброго времени суток, господа!
Такой вопрос: Как можно найти минимальное остовное дерево "второе" по весу?
к примеру, если сумма весов ребер минимального остовного дерева равна 20, то сумма "второго" по весу ребер остовного дерева должна быть > 20.

Answer (score 1):

Мое имхо, не претендую на оптимальность: перебор по дереву возможных решений с отсечением заведомо неверных комбинаций.

Мои имхо мысли:

Перебор нужен, потому что для нахождения именно "второго" решения нужно знать все остальные. Зная все решения можно так же сказать, что "второго" решения на графе не существует.

В общем случае для нахождения не "второго", а k-того решения нужно завести кучу (min heap) размером k + 1, и добавлять туда размеры решений. (Если в графе могут быть ребра одинакового размера, то нужен еще set, что бы не добавлять в кучу дубликаты). Все размеры которые "выпадают" из кучи (находятся дальше k-го индекса включительно в массиве) можно сразу игнорировать и перезаписывать.

Для генерации дерева решений нужно модифицировать алгоритм Прима, и вместо выбора ребра с минимальным весом нужно рассматривать все подходящие ребра (которые не образуют циклов). Если обходить все решения "в глубину" и рассматривать решения в порядке возрастания весов на каждом шаге, большую часть решений можно будет отсеять по критерию: вес недостроенного остова больше максимального значения в куче. Можно хранить макс. значение отдельно или просто попытаться вставить элемент в кучу и он "выпадет".

После обхода дерева нужно вытолкнуть все элементы из кучи, последний будет решением.

Конкретно для поиска "второго" решения можно просто сначала найти минимальный остов (min1), а потом проходя по дереву решений искать минимальное решение, отличное от min1.

Comment: Спасибо за идею!

Answer (score 0):

1. http://algolib.narod.ru/Graph/Ostov.html
2. http://rain.ifmo.ru/cat/view.php/theory/graph-spanning-trees/mst-2005

Comment: Спасибо конечно, но это не то, что я хотел узнать)

Answer (score 0):

Предположим все рёбра различны (это требуется для единственности минимального остова), в противном случаи 2 по весу понятие растяжимое. Существует Лемма:

> Минимальный остов является остовом с минимальным весом самого тяжёлого ребра

Это практически очевидно если рассмотреть алгоритм Крускала. 
Будет строить дерево именно этим алгоритмом http://e-maxx.ru/algo/mst_kruskal
Но при добавлении последнего ребра пропустим нужный по алгоритму элемент, и возьмём следующий подходящий. Должно сработать.